# Swift: Cannot add element in Array from another object

Tags: arrays, swift, macos-catalina

I am struggeling with swift syntax . I want to add objects to an array but I have syntax errors.
The array is located in class Document, and the class that should add objects is in class Viewcontroller.

The array is of type Content:

```
public class Content: NSObject  {
    @objc var bankAccSender: String?
    @objc var bankAccReceiver: String?
```

Declaration snippest in Document:

```
class Document: NSDocument  {
    
    var content=[Content]()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.content = [Content]()
        
        // force one data record to insert into  content 
        content += [Content (… )]      // checked with debugger
```

The ViewController has assigned the represented Object

```
contentVC.representedObject = content
```

But adding data in ViewController gives a compiler error „Type of expression is ambiguous without more context“:

```
var posting = Content(…)
self.representedObject.append(posting)
```

Hope you can help..

Answer (score 2):

You can't append an element to an object of type `Any`. What you need is to replace the existing value with a new collection:

```
representedObject = (representedObject as? [Content] ?? []) + CollectionOfOne(posting)
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, it is really tricky. Unfortunately, both of your statements raises errors. Statement is : "Cannot use mutating member on immutable  value of type [content]". I will see if Leo's answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

`representedObject` is of type `Any?`, which is a very difficult type to work with in Swift. Since you already have a `content` property, I would probably adjust that, and then re-assign it to `representedObject`.

You can also try this (untested), as long as you are certain that the type is always `[Content]`:

```
(self.representedObject as! [Content]).append(posting)
```

It's possible you'll need some more complex like this:

```
(self.representedObject as! [Content]?)!.append(posting)
```

As I said, `Any?` is an incredibly obnoxious type. You probably want to wrap this up into a function. Or I you can avoid using `representedObject`, then I would recommend that. In many cases you don't need it. It's often just a convenience (in ObjC; in Swift, it's very hard to use).

Comment: Thanks Rob, it is really tricky. Unfortunately, both of you statements raises errors.